# Enviar dados de combobox e checkbox para outra tabela

Tags: php, javascript, html

Primeiro o do botão `submit` que perde a ação quando coloco meu *script* para configurar minha tabela. Segundo preciso fazer alguns passos:

1. Carrego um *combobox* com dados de determinada tabela, ou seja nomes de alguns colaboradores.
2. Carrego minha tabela com dados de outra tabela, nome dos clientes.
3. Preciso selecionar o nome de um colaborador e um, ou vários, clientes  através de `checkbox` na tabela e enviar estes dados para outra tabela. Ou seja a tabela será composta pelo ID do colaborador lincado ao ID do Cliente, que no caso seria o colaborador responsável por aqueles clientes.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(function(){

      $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');

      $('table > tbody > tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
      });

      $('#marcar-todos').click(function(){
        $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox')
          .attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
          .trigger('change');
      });

      $('table > tbody > tr > td > :checkbox').bind('click change', function(){
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).is(':checked')) $(tr).addClass('selected');
        else $(tr).removeClass('selected');
      });

      $('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

      $('#pesquisar').keydown(function(){
        var encontrou = false;
        var termo = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('table > tbody > tr').each(function(){
          $(this).find('td').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(termo) > -1) encontrou = true;
          });
          if(!encontrou) $(this).hide();
          else $(this).show();
          encontrou = false;
        });
      });

      $("table") 
        .tablesorter({
          dateFormat: 'uk',
          headers: {
            0: {
              sorter: false
            },
            5: {
              sorter: false
            }
          }
        }) 
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")})
        .bind('sortEnd', function(){
          $('table > tbody > tr').removeClass('odd');
          $('table > tbody > tr:odd').addClass('odd');
        });

    });
    </script>
```

**HTML / PHP**

```
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/_cadastro.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/form.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="_imagens/icone.ico">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/dataCad.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/formatarMascara.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <?php
        include_once("conexao2.php");

        $sqlProfessor="SELECT IdProf, NomeProf FROM professor" ;

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlProfessor);

        ?>

  <div id="interface">
    <header id="cabecalho">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Clínica Escola</h1>
            <h2>Cadastro</h2>
        </hgroup>

         <img id="imgpos" src="../_imagens/psicologia.png"/>
        <img id="imgpos2" src="../_imagens/logo-pitagoras.png"/>
    </header>

    <header id="corpo">


    <form >
    <div id="formulario">

             <div class="esquerda" id="">


         <label for="">Selecione um Professor</label>
         <select name="professor" >
         <option>Selecione...</option>

         <?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$prod['IdProf'] .'">'.$prod['NomeProf'].'</option>'."\n";

          } 
          ?>

         </select>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
<br>
<br>
<br>

    <form  method="post" action="testaPHP.php" >
      <p>
        <label for="pesquisar">Pesquisar</label>
        <input type="text" id="pesquisar" name="pesquisar" size="30" />
      </p>
    </form>

    <?php

        $sql="SELECT c.IdCliente,c.NomeCliente,c.IdadeCliente,c.Celular,s.NomeStatus FROM cliente c,Status s WHERE c.IdStatus=s.IdStatus" ;

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


    echo"
    <table cellspacing='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type='checkbox' value='1' id='marcar-todos' name='marcar-todos' /></th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Idade</th>
          <th>Telefone</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>";

      while($escrever=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          foreach($escrever AS $key => $value) { $escrever[$key] = stripslashes($value); }

      echo "<tbody>";
       echo" <tr>";
  echo "<td valign='top'><input type='checkbox' name='ativo[]'value={$escrever['IdCliente']}>";
        echo"<td>".$escrever['IdCliente']."</td>";
          echo"<td>".$escrever['NomeCliente']."</td>";
          echo"<td>".$escrever['IdadeCliente']."</td>";
         echo" <td>".$escrever['Celular']."</td>";
          echo"<td>".$escrever['NomeStatus']."</td>";
          echo"<td>";
           echo" <a href='#'><img src='edit.png' width='16' height='16' /></a>";
           echo" <a href='#'><img src='delete.png' width='16' height='16' /></a>";
          echo"</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
      echo"</tbody>";
      }
    echo"</table>";

    ?>

    <div id="pager" class="pager">
        <form>
                <span>
                    Exibir <select class="pagesize">
                            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option  value="40">40</option>
                    </select> registros
                </span>

                <img src="first.png" class="first"/>
            <img src="prev.png" class="prev"/>
            <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
            <img src="next.png" class="next"/>
            <img src="last.png" class="last"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <form name="prof" method="post" action="check.php">
        <input type="submit" /> 
    </form> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual a lógica que você pensou ao fazer o `preventDefault` do evento `submit` dos formulários? Você sabe o que esta linha faz?

Comment: Anderson, na verdade eu tenho pouco conhecimento em html e php, era para ser desenvolvido em java web,mas a equipe achou melhor em PHP

Comment: Anderson na Verdade eu estou reutilizando o código e desconhecia desta funcionalidade, comentei ele aqui e não interferiu em nada, sua ajuda já valeu agora vou tentar o restante, vc tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Esse código evitada que o formulário fosse submetido. Espero que agora o primeiro problema tenha sido resolvido. Já o segundo está bem confuso. Se você puder apresentar um [mcve], acredito que facilitará o entendimento.

Comment: Anderson, Obrigado pela ajuda eu consegui resolver aqui. Sua ajuda foi fundamental